# how can i add items in youtubeplaylist?

Tags: php, api, curl, youtube

I am trying to use this code to insert item in youtubeplaylist and its not working as i want ...  i think its showing me if playlist contain this id .

please check and let me know what i need to change in code to insert this ID in my playlist .

Here is code :

```
$option = array(
        'part' => 'snippet', 
        'mine' => 'true',
        'key' => 'AIzaSyCJlbT_sqTG2nOUMYU24WzzxXpOelaiYTA',
        'access_token' => $_SESSION['info']['access_token'],
        'playlistId' => $ID, 
        'kind' => 'youtube#video',
        'videoId' => 'KMGuyGY5gvY',
    );
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?".http_build_query($option, 'a', '&');
$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
$curlheader[0] = "Authorization: Bearer " . $_SESSION['info']['access_token'];
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curlheader);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$responseObj = json_decode($json_response);
```

thanks in advance.